# Passing a literal with the "in" parameter modifier

Tags: c#

It is not clear why C# doesn't allow calling a method passing a literal together with the `in` parameter modifier; at the same time, when the literal passed to the method without the `in` parameter modifier the code compiles.

Here is a code example that demonstrates this behavior (C# 7.3):

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = string.Empty;

        //These two lines compile 
        WriteStringToConsole(in s);
        WriteStringToConsole("my string");

        //Error CS8156  An expression cannot be used in this context because it may not be passed or returned by reference 
        WriteStringToConsole(in "my string");
    }

    public static void WriteStringToConsole (in string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: The in keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference. It makes the formal parameter an alias for the argument, which must be a variable.

Comment: @GoodSamaritan you should probably add the link you're quoting in your comment.

Comment: You don't need the "in" in the calling method. Only it is needed in the method declaration.

Comment: The only meaning of the "in" is, to prevent passing literals and properties.
If you don't want to prevent it, don't use it.

Answer (score 5):

As specified in the [C# language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier), you cannot use a constant with the `in` keyword as an argument:

> The argument used with in must represent a location that can be directly referred to. The same general rules for out and ref arguments apply: you cannot use constants, ordinary properties, or other expressions that produce values.

Answer (score 1):

In C# 7.2, “in parameter” has been introduced which allows passing read-only reference of a variable. Before C# 7.2, we used “ref” and “out” keywords for passing the references of a variable. “Out” is meant for output only whereas ‘ref’ is meant for input and output both. However, if we had to pass a read-only reference, i.e., passing a variable as input only, then there was no direct option for that. So, in C# 7.2, “in parameter” has been introduced for this purpose

You can refer below answer for the right use **`in`** parameter

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52825832/3992001

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteStringToConsole("test"); // OK, temporary variable created.
            string test = "test";
            WriteStringToConsole(test); // OK, temporary int created with the value 0
            WriteStringToConsole(in test); // passed by readonly reference, explicitly using `in`
            //Not allowed
            WriteStringToConsole(in "test"); //Error CS8156  An expression cannot be used in this context because it may not be passed or returned by reference

        }
        static void WriteStringToConsole(in string argument)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(argument);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is clear why the `in` modifier can't be used with a literal while calling a method with the `in` parameter modifier; the `ref` and `out` modifiers don't allow it too:

[in parameter modifier (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier)

> The argument used with `in` must represent a location that can be
> directly referred to. The same general rules for `out` and `ref` arguments
> apply: You cannot use constants, ordinary properties, or other
> expressions that produce values.

When you want to pass to a method with the `in` parameter modifier a literal without the `in` modifier then the compiler creates a temporary variable and uses a reference to this variable calling the method. It is done for the following reasons:

[in parameter modifier (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier)

> Omitting `in` at the call site informs the compiler that you will allow
> it to create a temporary variable to pass by read-only reference to
> the method. **The compiler creates a temporary variable to overcome
> several restrictions with in arguments**:
>
> - A temporary variable allows compile-time constants as `in` parameters.
> - A temporary variable allows properties, or other expressions for `in` parameters.
> - A temporary variable allows arguments where there is an
>   implicit conversion from the argument type to the parameter type.

To summarize, both options are allowed since each of them has a different usage case, but eventually, a read-only reference to a variable used anyway.